# Will my Pelakka Wurm still deal trample damage vs Deathtouch?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was playing my son using a green deck.  I played a [Pelakka Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pelakka%20Wurm) which has trample.  He played an Eldrazi with deathtouch.  He is a firm believer as soon as the attackers and blockers are announced, the deathtouch would kill the Wurm.  I tried to get him to understand it would be taken care of in the damage phase and the Trample would in fact still do its damage.

Now, I know that Trample damage will take affect on the defending player only after it does lethal dmg to the blocking creature.  So, I announce the attackers and he announces the defenders.  The issue I have is, would my dmg take affect before his deathtouch does.  I believe my dmg is resolved first, activating the trample.  His dmg is activated second, satisfying the rules for deathtouch to work.  That card would destroy the Wurm, but the Wurm would complete the Trample before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do deathtouch and deathtouch-like effects stop trample damage?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18851/do-deathtouch-and-deathtouch-like-effects-stop-trample-damage) or [Trample + Deathtouch](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/trample-deathtouch)

Comment: It's "Do deathtouch and deathtouch-like effects stop trample damage?". The other one only sounds similarily but it cares about a different matter.

Answer (score 6):

All combat damage happens at the same time.

Your son assigns the damage with the Eldrazi. You assign the damage with Pelakka Wurm. If Wurm's power is higher then Eldrazi's toughness you'll be able to assign the surplus to your son.

Then all damage is dealt at the same time. Your wurm dies, as Eldrazi had deathtouch. But the Wurm also does it's damage to the Eldrazi and, possibly, your son.

If Eldrazi had First Stike - that would be a different story.

Comment: Somewhat relevant, there is an interesting interaction between trample and deathtouch. If an attacker has 8 power, trample and deathtouch and it is blocked by a creature with i.e. 5 toughness, the attacker will deal 7 trample damage to the player since 1 damage with deathtouch is enough to kill the creature.

Answer (score 1):

Your wurm deals damage to the eldrazi, any damage over the eldrazi's health is dealt to the player instead. At the same time, the eldrazi deals damage to your wurm. Since the eldrazi has deathtouch, as long as at least 1 point of damage is dealt by it, the opposing creature will be killed. The only way in which deathtouch would "prevent" trample is if the eldrazi had First Strike or Double Strike where it'd deal damage before the wurm.

702.2. Deathtouch

702.2b Any nonzero amount of combat damage assigned to a creature by a source with deathtouch is considered to be lethal damage, regardless of that creature’s toughness. See rules 510.1c–d.